# Get file contents via xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, windows, command-line, xp-cmdshell

Is there way to get file from windows xp command prompt? I tried to run `xp_cmdshell 'type [path to file]'` but then when i insert theese data into other file and renaming it to file.exe (that is executable) it does not work. Any suggestions how to get file contents in such way that i can use it?

Comment: What is xpcmdshell?  Do you mean the SQL extended stored procedure, xp_cmdshell?

Comment: Probably you need to convert the binary data into text form and back, e.g., base64 encoding.  AFAIK there is no way to do this using only built-in Windows utilities.  Can you make use of a third-party application, or are you limited to what is already on the server?

Comment: I am limited only to console, I cannot install anything. When I try to see content of text file with Latin chars, it works. Otherwise not. And could you link me to example of binary data conversion?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use BULK INSERT on the file and treat the file as a table with one row and one column. This should allow you to read the file directly into a VARBINARY field

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE FileRead
(
  content VARBINARY(MAX)
)

BULK INSERT FileRead FROM [FilePath]
```

This requires SQL Server to have access to the file you are trying to read. It sounds like you are trying to "acquire" executables from a server you do not have access to? :-)